# Change cursor bar in NetLogo 6?

Tags: netlogo

In NetLogo 6.0.2 in the Code tab, there is a cursor bar on the entire line being edited, rather than, say, a block cursor on the character being edited.  I understand the point of the cursor bar, but I find it annoying.  It always looks as if I have highlighted the code on that line and am about to replace it.  I have looked in the GUI and in the docs for a way to change the cursor behavior, but I haven't found it.  My guess is that it can't be changed, but if there is a way, I would love to know about it.

(I'm assuming this behavior is the same in the latest version, 6.0.3, but I can't yet install that version because of a MacOS version incompatibility with the install packaging (unless I compile it myself--not worth the trouble now).  I submitted an issue about the problem.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My guess is that it can't be changed

Your guess is correct.

(Unless you are willing to change it in the source and repackage NetLogo yourself. See [this commit](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/pull/1442/commits/df93e60dd9825c21b2a4c20162c75ab755f16665) for an example of how to change the color.)

> I understand the point of the cursor bar, but I find it annoying.

Ditto. It might be worth [suggesting a new feature](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/help.shtml#suggestions-for-new-features) for making the current line highlight color configurable.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas!  I will suggest a feature.  So far it's not annoying enough for my current needs to install my own version (I only use NetLogo occasionally), but I have done that in the past and if I go that route in the future, I'll make the change in my version.  Thanks for the pointer to the issue with the exact source location.